# Using sql alias names with jtable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, jtable

im struggling to get my jtable to work when joining 2 tables in the select statement.

Here is a snippet from the jtable javascript code of the current field names:

```
fields: {
    userID: {
        key: true,
        create: false,
        edit: false,
        list: false
    },
    CDTitle: {
        title: 'Album Title',
        edit: false,
        width: '30%'
    },
    reviewDate: {
        title: 'Review date',
        width: '20%',
        type: 'date',
        displayFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        create: false,
        edit: false
    },
    reviewText: {
        title: 'Review',
        type: 'textarea',
        width: '40%'
    }
}
```

userID, reviewDate and reviewText are all from the same table in the database called cdreview. CDTitle is from another table called cd and has sone of the same field names as cdreview (CDID) so I need to use alias names to join the 2 tables in my select statement. Currently my select statement is:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tiptop_cdreview where userID = " . $_GET["userID"] . ";");
```

I need the statement as:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT rev.*, cd.CDTitle FROM tiptop_cdreview rev, tiptop_cd cd where rev.userID = " . $_GET["userID"] . ";");
```

I changed the field names in the javascript to match the fieldnames in my select statement but I get:

```
Error: Expected ':'
```

Im guessing its because of the '.' in the javascript field names. What do I set the javascript fields to?

Comment: Note that you're currently open to SQL Injection, which will be found and exploited by automated tools.  Please use prepared statements (this site has plenty of examples).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thanks for pointing this out. Part of the assignment is to protect against these so I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Seem to have this working now without changing the field names in the javascript. My sql statement was wrong. Forgot to join the 2 tables together:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT rev.*, cd.CDTitle FROM tiptop_cdreview rev, tiptop_cd cd where cd.CDID = rev.CDID and rev.userID = " . $_GET["userID"] . ";");